# A net of weighted integrable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $\omega:[0,+\infty)\to (0,+\infty)$ be a continuous function such that $\omega(x+y)\leq\omega(x)\omega(y)$ and $\omega(0)=1$. Suppose that $m=\lim_{t\to+\infty} \frac{\ln \omega(t)}{-t}<\infty$

I want to prove that for **EVERY** net of complex-valued functions $\{f_\alpha:[0,+\infty)\to C\}_{\alpha\in\Gamma}$  such that for all $\alpha\in\Gamma$, $\int_0^\infty|f_\alpha(t)|w(t)dt<+\infty$, **if** there is $z_0\in C$, with $Re(z_0)\geq m$ such that 
$$\lim_\alpha\int_0^\infty f_\alpha(t)e^{-z_0t}dt= 1,$$ then there is  $z_1\in C$, with $Re(z_1)\geq m$ and $z_1\neq z_0$ such that
$$\lim_\alpha\int_0^\infty f_\alpha(t)e^{-z_1t}dt\neq 0.$$

If it is difficult, we can choose special $\omega$. For instance $\omega(t)=e^{-t}$ or $\omega(t)=(1+t)$.